# AngularJS Ng-repeat group by and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an array from an Azure server Log (clicks array) that i would like to order, this is the request:

```
$http({
      method: 'Get',
      headers: {
       'Host': 'api.applicationinsights.io',
       'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       },

       url: 'https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/20exxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cf8bc569d261/query?query=requests | where timestamp > datetime(2018-03-13) and timestamp <= datetime(2018-03-22) %2B 1d | where name contains "GetCode" | where name contains "9278"'
       })
         .success(function (data) {
          $scope.clicks = data.tables[0].rows;
          console.log($scope.clicks)
          })
```

this is the array i get out (about 275.000 rows):

```
0:
Array(37)
0:"2018-03-22T08:37:02.982Z"
1:"|ypdKJH+nmLI=.aeeeecd8_"
2:null
3:"GET /content/GetCode/192.0/9278"
etc.
1:
Array(37)
0:"2018-03-22T08:37:04.877Z"
1:"|nynZFXWHS7g=.aeeeece2_"
2:null
3:"GET /content/GetCode/1773.0/9278"
etc.
```

now i only use [3] in this case in my NG-Repet so i made the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="click in clicks">
    click: {{(click[3].split('GET /content/GetCode/')[1]).split('/9278')[0]}}
</div>
```

it gives me nicely the list of times

```
192.0
1773.0
198.5
112,0
32.8
3148.7
etc. x 100.000
```

how would i be able to group this list in lets say each minute, so i collect all of them together in groups of 30 sec.

so like this:

```
  0- 30: 0
 31- 60: 1 (aka 32.8)
 61- 90: 0
 91-120: 1 (aka 112.0)
121-150: 0
151-180: 0
181-210: 2 (aka 192.0 & 198.5)
211-240: 0 etc. etc. you get the idea i guess.
```

How would i be able to do this?

Comment: please provide complete clicks array

Comment: there is not easy solution, but to do everything manually. You should sort the array by date, then mark the first element as `0` seconds,  mark the last element as `Math.floor((last+30)/30)` seconds. Then simply iterate over all elements populating them into these groups with 30 seconds intervals

Comment: Your best bet would be to create your own custom directive, component, and/or filter.  If you're trying to do this with some built in AngularJS function you may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: how in that case would i first move the " .split('GET /content/GetCode/')[1]).split('/9278')[0] " to a filter?

Comment: @EwaldBos filter it first, then split the result

Comment: yes but the array dates are different, how would i sort the 3:"GET /content/GetCode/192.0/9278" arrays that are in the log by the time that is inside the string? in that case i need to first get the times out. The dates of the log are not in corresponding with the order of the times.

Comment: then make a copy of that array with `angular.copy($scope.clicks)` and split the values there, after that you can safely sort the array, but I'm not sure how you will replicate filtering on the original array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JS for that:

```
  $scope.groupedArray = []
  var clicks = {
    1: [
      'asd', 'asdasd', 'GET /content/GetCode/192.0/9278'
    ],
    2: [
      'asd', 'asdasd', 'GET /content/GetCode/1773.0/9278'
    ]
  }
  var a = []
  for (var key in clicks) {
    a.push((clicks[key][2].split('GET /content/GetCode/')[1]).split('/9278')[0])
  }
  a = a.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })
  for(let i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
    arrayIndex = parseInt(a[i]/30);
    $scope.groupedArray[arrayIndex] = ($scope.groupedArray[arrayIndex] == undefined) ? 1 : ($scope.groupedArray[arrayIndex] + 1);
  }
  for(let i = 0; i<$scope.groupedArray.length; i++) {
    $scope.groupedArray[i] = ($scope.groupedArray[i] == undefined) ? 0 : $scope.groupedArray[i]
  }
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in groupedArray">
    {{($index) * 30}} - {{($index + 1) * 30}} -> {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i get the first complete part to work, just the HTML does not output anything yet. A console.log on $scope.groupedArray shows me all the sections tho. I just don't understand the HTML section so no idea how to fix it as well

Comment: Sorry my bad, need to remove $scope, 
Pls try it now